# How to add/subtract days from a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

Let's say I have this table :

```
DECLARE @Var INT  
SET @Var = (select day from source)
SELECT * FRom TMP
INTO #TARGET
Where tmp.date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0) - @Var
          tmp.date  <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

The query get the result if `@val != 0` but don't work when `@val=0`

Comment: `dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)` - this thing cuts time from date and nothing more. Same as casting to `date` type. When @var is zero you have to equal dates. You `tmp.date` stores dates with time. So finally you are trying to locate records with for example `tmp.date = 2015-03-01 12:30:451` by applying this filter: `tmp.date >= "2015-03-01 00:00:00" and tmp.date >= "2015-03-01 00:00:00"` which is obviously always false.

Comment: *_to equal dates_ -> two equal dates. yeah, and filter `>= ... <=` of course.

Comment: @IvanStarostin oh yeeess you are right know i understand , so i thank i should do this :  `tmp.date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0) - @Var AND tmp.date <=dateadd(dd, -0, GETDATE())`

Comment: just copy and paste lines from my answer. it misses only @var definition.

Comment: You should avoid doing *so many things* in where predicate. Keep it clear to server's query optimizer and to yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
DECLARE @Var INT  
SET @Var = (select day from source)
SELECT * FRom TMP
INTO #TARGET
Where tmp.date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0) - @Var
          tmp.date  <= GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

of course, 'cause your upper range bound is the same date and since you have time stored in that column you receive nothing.

```
declare
  @datebegin date = getdate(),
  @dateend date = getdate()

...

set @datebegin = dateadd(dd, -@var, @datebegin)
set @dateend = dateadd(dd, 1, @dateend) /* till the end of this day */

SELECT * FRom TMP
INTO #TARGET
Where tmp.date >= @datebegin and tmp.date  < @dateend
```

calc as much as you can before the final query

Comment: I need time to get all line on table tmp starting on the begining of day

Comment: Have another look at `where` predicate.

Comment: This `SELECT dateadd(dd, -0, GETDATE())` retirn this value `2016-03-01 10:59:55.103` and i need the start time of day  somthing like this `2016-03-01 00:00:00`

Comment: ..have you tried my approach? do you see `date` datatype? why are you showing me things which have nothing common with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Try put @var inside dateadd:

```
dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE())- @Var,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

When @var is 0 you are trying to get vales for the day at 00:00:00.
For exemple
tmp.date >= '2016-03-01 00:00:00' and  tmp.date <= '2016-03-01 00:00:00'

If the tmp table has hours like '2016-03-01 08:00:00', this value is not selected.

Comment: Yes I need use time to extract from TMP table all row starting on the begining of day ,

Comment: In that case you need to change query to tmp.date  < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE())+1,0)